# Change download location to "Downloads" in Pytube in Python

Tags: python, html, css, django, pytube

I want to change the download location to "Downloads" in pytube in Python. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: `stream.download('<path>')` https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html

Comment: I want to change the download location to Downloads can you give me the path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
from pytube import YouTube

youtube = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5m8BAffnuA8&list=PLTgRMOcmRb3PQEztkPnMvAeehReJPoSNP')

my_video = youtube.streams.first()

my_video.download('~/Downloads')
```

Comment: It's saying unresolved reference "OPTIONS". Can you solve this?

Comment: I want to change the download location to Downloads can you give me the path?

Comment: what do you pass in as options? 
it should be like this: 

youtube.get('mp4', '720p')

Note: it can be anything.

Comment: it's showing ---- AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Seems get method is deprecated, I updated the post, check it now.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the output?

Comment: By the assumption that you are using a Linux distribution, after `my_video.download('~/Downloads')` , You should be seeing the video file which you downloaded in your home directory. 
If not instead of `'~/Downloads'`, place your own path.

Comment: No, I don't want to download my video in the current project directory. I want to download it in the windows default download location that means Downloads.

Comment: OK then, check this:
`username = os.getlogin()` and then, 
`my_video.download(f'C:/Users/{username}')`

Comment: Thank you it downloaded in the Downloads actually my download location is E:/Down. I changed the download path to Downloads then it downloaded in the downloads. Sorry for the trouble and Thank you very very much:)

Answer (score 0):

use can use this

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

path_to_download = str(os.path.join(Path.home(), 'Downloads'))
stream.download()
```